# SATA and ATA as master

Tags: sata, ata

Can I have both SATA and ATA as master?
If Yes which one is first for booting ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming its a modern motherboard and you're asking can I boot from either one the answer is YES.  Which is first depends on how much flexibility your BIOS setup gives you.  You should be able to pick the boot HD regardless of what type it is but you'll have to explore the BIOS boot setup options a bit to do that.